# Laravel 7 CRUD (Update) doesn't have error but db is not updating

Tags: sql, ajax, laravel, database, crud

I am trying to update a data but it doesn't change in the database. The ajax tells that the data is successful and the console did not show any error. Please help me. I need to finish this before April 22. Thank you.

**Model**

*Health.php*

```
public function UpdateChild($request){
        $child_id = $request->input('child_id');
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $zone = $request->input('zone');
        $mothersname = $request->input('mothersname');
        $childsname = $request->input('childsname');
        $ind_id = $request->input('ind_id');
        $sex_id = $request->input('sex_id');
        $birthdate = $request->input('birthdate');
        $actualdate = $request->input('actualdate');
        $weight = $request->input('weight');
        $height = $request->input('height');
        $ageinmonths = $request->input('ageinmonths');

        $result = DB::update('UPDATE childs SET id = ?, zone = ?, mothersname = ?, childsname = ?, ind_id = ?, sex_id = ?, 
        birthdate = ?, actualdate = ?, weight = ?, height = ?, ageinmonths = ? WHERE child_id = ?', 
        [$id, $zone, $mothersname, $childsname, $ind_id, $sex_id, $birthdate, $actualdate, $weight, $height, $ageinmonths, $child_id]);

        //$result = DB::table('childs')->where('child_id', $request)->update(array('zone'=>$zone));

        return $result;
        //$result->save();
    }
```

**Controller**

*healthcontroller.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use App\Health;
    use Auth;

class healthcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function health(){

        $sex = Health::retrieveSex();
        $indigenous = Health::retrieveIndigenous();
        return view('healthview', compact('sex', 'indigenous'));
    }

    public function showData(){

        $user = Health::RetrieveUser();

        return response()->json($user);
    }

    public function delete_child(Request $request){

        $result = new Health();

        $result->DeleteChild($request);

        return response()->json($result);
    }

    public function insert_child(Request $request){

        $result = new Health();

        $result->InsertChild($request);

        return response()->json($result);
    }

    public function update_child(Request $request){

        $result = new Health();

        $result->UpdateChild($request);
        
        return response()->json($result);
    }

    public function upload(){
        
        return view('upload');
    }
}
```

**Modal**

```
<div id="modalUpdateChild" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Update Child</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="update_Child" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="child_idx">Child ID:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_idx" name="child_idx" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="useridx">User ID:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="useridx" name="useridx" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="zonex">Zone:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zonex" name="zonex" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="mothersnamex">Mother's Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mothersnamex" name="mothersnamex" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="childsnamex">Child's Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="childsnamex" name="childsnamex" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Indigenous:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="ind_idx" name="ind_idx" required>
                                <option value="">YES or NO</option>
                                @foreach ($indigenous as $key => $value)
                                <option id="{{ $key }}" value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Sex:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="sex_idx" name="sex_idx" required>
                                <option value="">M or F</option>
                                @foreach ($sex as $key => $value)
                                <option id="{{ $key }}" value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Date of Birth:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthdatex" name="birthdatex"
                                placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Actual Date of Weighing:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="actualdatex" name="actualdatex"
                                placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Weight(kg):</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="weightx" name="weightx" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Height(cm):</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="heightx" name="heightx" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Age In Months:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ageinmonthsx" name="ageinmonthsx" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-flat btn-success" id="ageBtn">Calculate Age</button>
                        </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary" id="saveChangesBtn">Save Changes</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
<!--UPDATE MODAL SCRIPT-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#data_list').on('click', '.UpdateChild', function() {

    var child_id = $(this).data('child_id');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var zone = $(this).data('zone');
    var mothersname = $(this).data('mothersname');
    var childsname = $(this).data('childsname');
    var ind_id = $(this).data('ind_id');
    var sex_id = $(this).data('sex_id');
    var birthdate = $(this).data('birthdate');
    var actualdate = $(this).data('actualdate');
    var weight = $(this).data('weight');
    var height = $(this).data('height');
    var ageinmonths = $(this).data('ageinmonths');

    $('#child_idx').val(child_id);
    $('#useridx').val(id);
    $('#zonex').val(zone);
    $('#mothersnamex').val(mothersname);
    $('#childsnamex').val(childsname);
    $('#ind_idx').val(ind_id);
    $('#sex_idx').val(sex_id);
    $('#birthdatex').val(birthdate);
    $('#actualdatex').val(actualdate);
    $('#weightx').val(weight);
    $('#heightx').val(height);
    $('#ageinmonthsx').val(ageinmonths);

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to edit this data?")) {
        $('#modalUpdateChild').modal('show');
    }
    return false;
});
</script>

<!--UPDATE DATA SCRIPT-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#update_Child').submit('click', function(event) {

    var child_id = $('child_idx').val();
    var id = $('#useridx').val();
    var zone = $('#zonex').val();
    var mothersname = $('#mothersnamex').val();
    var childsname = $('#childsnamex').val();
    var ind_id = $('#ind_idx').val();
    var sex_id = $('#sex_idx').val();
    var birthdate = $('#birthdatex').val();
    var actualdate = $('#actualdatex').val();
    var weight = $('#weightx').val();
    var height = $('#heightx').val();
    var ageinmonths = $('#ageinmonthsx').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            child_id: child_id,
            id: id,
            zone: zone,
            mothersname: mothersname,
            childsname: childsname,
            ind_id: ind_id,
            sex_id: sex_id,
            birthdate: birthdate,
            actualdate: actualdate,
            weight: weight,
            height: height,
            ageinmonths: ageinmonths
        },
        url: "update_child",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Data successfully changed.");
            displayData();
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$('#saveChangesBtn').click(function() {
    $('#modalUpdateChild').modal('hide');
});

$('#modalUpdateChild').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this)
        .find("input,textarea,select")
        .val('')
        .end()
        .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
        .prop("checked", "")
        .end();
})
</script>
```

**Blade(view)**

*healthview.blade.php*

```
<div class="container-md" style="margin-right: 230px;">
        <div class="container">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning" href="health">Home</a>
            <button href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddChild"
                style="float: right;">Add</button>
            <br>
            <h2 class="text-primary"><strong>Childs' Nutritional Status Predictor</strong></h2>
            <p><i>Note: Double click the trash icon to delete a data.</i></p>
            <table class="table table-bordered text-center" id="data_table" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Child ID</th>
                        <th>Address/Zone</th>
                        <th>Name of Mother/Caregiver</th>
                        <th>Fullname of Child</th>
                        <th>Indigenous</th>
                        <th>Sex</th>
                        <th>Date of Birth</th>
                        <th>Actual Date of Weighing</th>
                        <th>Weight</th>
                        <th>Height</th>
                        <th>Age In Months</th>
                        <th>Weight Status</th>
                        <th>Health Status</th>
                        <th>Weight for Length</th>
                        <!--<th class="text-primary">View</th>-->
                        <th class="text-yellow">Edit</th>
                        <th class="text-danger">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="data_list">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
displayData();

function displayData() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "showData",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data) {

            var html;
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                html += '<tr>';

                html += '<td>' + data[i].child_id + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].zone + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].mothersname + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].childsname + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].indigenous + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].sex + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].birthdate + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].actualdate + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].weight + ' kg</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].height + ' cm</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].ageinmonths + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].weightstatus + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].heightstatus + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + data[i].weightforlengthstatus + '</td>';
                //html += '<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary ReadChild" data-toggle="modal" data-child_id="'+data[i].child_id+'" data-zone="'+data[i].zone+'" data-mothersname="'+data[i].mothersname+'" data-childsname="'+data[i].childsname+'" data-ind_id="'+data[i].ind_id+'" data-sex_id="'+data[i].sex_id+'" data-birthdate="'+data[i].birthdate+'" data-actualdate="'+data[i].actualdate+'" data-weight="'+data[i].weight+'" data-height="'+data[i].height+'" data-id="'+data[i].id+'"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></td>';

                html += '<td>';
                html +=
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-warning UpdateChild" data-child_id="' +
                    data[i].child_id + '" data-zone="' + data[i].zone + '" data-mothersname="' + data[i]
                    .mothersname + '" data-childsname="' + data[i].childsname + '" data-ind_id="' + data[i]
                    .ind_id + '" data-sex_id="' + data[i].sex_id + '" data-birthdate="' + data[i]
                    .birthdate + '" data-actualdate="' + data[i].actualdate + '" data-weight="' + data[i]
                    .weight + '" data-height="' + data[i].height + '" data-id="' + data[i].id +
                    '" data-ageinmonths="' + data[i].ageinmonths + '"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>';
                html += '</td>';

                html += '<td>';

                html +=
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger DeleteChild" title="Double Click To Delete" data-child_id="' +
                    data[i].child_id + '"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>';

                html += '</td>';
                //html += '<td>'+data[i].userid+'</td>';

                html += '</tr>';

            }

            $('#data_list').html(html);
        }

    });
}
</script>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('/main/update_child', 'healthcontroller@update_child');
```

Comment: why did you comment this line? 
        //$result = DB::table('childs')->where('child_id', $request)->update(array('zone'=>$zone)); I think you need to follow that, but if you want to use raw query, first you can change DB:update to DB:raw

Comment: at js whatever the response your alert fires `alert("Data successfully changed.");
            displayData();`
 I recommend testing it first without ajax for easier debugging

Comment: @VasoGamdelidze I tried putting that on before but nothing happened that is why I did comment it.